# Bootloader location in memory

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, bootloader, microchip

Is there a way to make the bootloader code occupy a specific section in program memory?

I noticed that some of the code is written in the top section of memory but the other part is written starting at section $11000. In my case it conflicts with my application code. So how do I force the bootloader code to occupy program memory starting from $00000 to $10000? I am assuming it can be done by changing some settings under Mplab XC8 compiler.

PIC: PIC18F87J11

Compiler: MPLAB XC8

**Update:**

Found the fix

Project properties > XC8 global options category > Memory Model > ROM ranges

ROM RANGE: 0-10000

**Update:**

I am seeing another issue though.

So I set the ROM range from **$00000-$10000**, but that's not enough space for the bootloader code even though it should. However when I look at the program memory under MPLAB XC8 after building the project, I noticed that there are some addressees left empty.

How do I force those addressees to be used? If those sections were used then the specified ROM size from 0-10000 should be enough for my bootloader code.

For example those addresses are used (data written there)

**00000-0925C**

But then these address are not used, just left blank

**0925E- 0F77A** (huge section, what a waste)

Then these addresses are used

**0F77C-0FFFE**

But then my program gets cut off at $10000 even though there seems to be more code to be written to memory.

So

How do I force those unused addressee to be used? Its just a huge waste of memory to skip them and I don't understand why they are empty. I can not give the Bootloader anymore ROM space, the rest must be given to the Application Code.

I hope everything is clear, thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with PIC, but typically you specify memory sections in the linker directive file.  Read the linker manual.

Comment: Under MPLAB C18, there are no gaps or unused addresses. However, with MPLAB XC8, some addresses are unused like described above, so the problem seems to be coming from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

To place the bootloader in the specified memory, you should:

1) In the code - create the section.

```
int __section("_bootloader") helper(int mode) {
/* ... */ 
//bootloader functions here
}
```

2) In the options of linker - add options to place the section to the specified memory.

```
-L-A_BLOADER=00h-ffffh
-L-p_bootloader=_BLOADER
```

To see the exect functions placed in the memory range 0F77C-0FFFE, you may see the *.map file (if it is generated).

Comment: I am not sure about your answer, looks very unfamiliar. My Bootloader project is separate than the Application project, so I am not about part 1 of your answer. Part 2 looks familiar but I don't think that's the way to fix it. Like I said, the problem seems to be coming from the compiler I am using. Under Mplab C18 there are no unused addresses, all of them are used. However, under Mplab XC8, I see gaps at some addresses in program memory. They should be used but they are not.